# Cannot find name 'X', even though name was imported directly above

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm not sure exactly what's going on here. The name is clearly imported directly above.

[image: Error]

Here's the content of `storage-backend.interface.ts`:

```
export declare interface StorageBackend extends Storage { }
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use interface for provider tokens since they doesn't exist at runtime. You need to use a class, a string or an `OpqueToken` instead.

Otherwise I would try the following:

```
export interface StorageBackend extends Storage { }
```

The `declare` keyword is to "declare" an element but in a definition file (`.d.ts`) not in a TypeScript module itself.